# Adding custom effect to button

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-animation, swipe

I have a button and implemented a swipe gesture on it

```
    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            myGestDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

 myGestDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {    boolean swipePerformed = true;
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
            {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+"  "+e2.toString());
                    if (e2.getX()- e1.getX()>900) {
                    btn1.setText("Order has been placed!");
                    Drawable img = Buttons.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_empty);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
            }});
```

Using e1.getX I can track the x position of starting and ending of the scroll. Now as the scroll happens I want to change the color of the button and track the scroll position. Think of a white progress bar where a blue colour comes to represent the progress. I want a colour in that way to come which follows the user's action. As of now, once the swipe is completed, the picture on the button changes.